# file attachment mail in php

Tags: php, html

hello I am working on html form submission via email. Server side scripting is P H P . my html form is

```
<form action='sendmail.php' method='post'>
   Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    File:<input type='file' name='attach'>
<input type="submit">
```

My php file for sending email is

```
<?php 
   $strTo = "xyz@gmail.com";
     $strHeader .= "From: ".$_POST["name"]."<".$_POST["name"].">";  
     $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
     $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
   $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";  
    $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
   $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n"; 
    $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"; 
    $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";  
    $strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";  
 if($_FILES["attach"]["name"] != "")
 {
        $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];  
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));  
       $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";  
         $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n";  
       $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
        $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";  
       $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
       }
 $flgSend = @mail($strTo,"no-subjet",null,$strHeader);
```

**but its not going in if condition**

Comment: I am not receiving attachment

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing your form with this:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    File:<input type="file" name="attach" id="attach">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The **enctype** attribute in the form is important.

See following link for more details:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Also ensure all the names in PHP match with HTML, such as the name of file input is **attach**, so it should be the same in PHP.

```
if($_FILES["attach"]["name"] != "")
{
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["attach"]["name"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll piggyback on your answer rather than adding my own - the name of the field doesn't match either. It's `name="attach"` in the HTML, but `$_FILES['fileAttach']` in the PHP.

Comment: AgentConundrum you are right, I was mainly answering the question why does not go into the condition. Added to the answer.